# How to disable google fonts for mobile in Joomla?

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, fonts

I use google fonts in my Joomla template here is my code

`$this->addStyleSheet( 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic');`

For mobile devices I want to disable google fonts at all. I found excelent solution but it works only when joomla cache is off

```
if (!JFactory::getApplication()->client->mobile) { 
    $this->addStyleSheet(
        'http://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic' 
      );
}
```

I am beginner in Javascript can anybody show me the valid code to disable google fonts for mobile devices.

Comment: This question is irrelevant. Sure you're using a custom template and it should have an admin interface that should allow you to enable/disable different features including the Google fonts.

Comment: Though if I am not right and this is you own template that you've built this `if (!JFactory::getApplication()->client->mobile) { ` will work like a charm

Comment: JFactory::getApplication()->client->mobile 
that code works if Joomla cache is disabled. But if I turn on Joomla cache it doesn't work any more. So I need javascipt solution for it.